# Eliminate isolated pixels in Google Earth Engine classified image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-classification

Is there a way to eliminate isolated pixels just like we can do with the `classification sieve` of the `QGIS SCP plugin`?

I've done a classification of an image that contains many isolated pixels which I want to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a focal operator or reduceNeighborhood with a mode reducer.

```
image.focalMode(3)
```

or

```
image.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mode(), ee.Kernel.circle(1))
```